# Push to multiple remote repositories from a single local repo in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, kiln, appharbor

I was considering using AppHarbor to host a lightweight website and was investigating their Mercurial integration.

Currently I use Kiln for my remote repositories, but currently AppHarbor only supports BitBucket integration.

Is it possible to have 2 remote repositories for a single local repository? So when I push commits from my local, they both get the push?

I don't ever want to pull from BitBucket, only push so that it can then be grabbed by AppHarbor and deployed.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can set multiple remote repository aliases in the `[paths]` section of the repository configuration file. This file is in .hg/hgrc, and you would add paths like this

```
[paths]
default = http://kilnhg.com/repo
bitbucket = http://bitbucket.org/repo
```

Then you would run `hg push bitbucket` to push to bitbucket and `hg push` to push to kiln, which is also the default here. The alias `default` is the one that's used when you don't specify anything else. This way push and pull with no arguments would use your preferred remote host, kiln.

Sadly you can't do a `hg push *` type command to push to all remote hosts at once, you have to specify each push destination one by one.

Comment: fantastic. I'll give it a go and report back!

Comment: looks like winner! The only thing is that file, for windows, was `.hg/hgrc` rather than `.hg/config`

Comment: Woops, typo/thinko. I was thinking of git's config file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can edit the hgrc file on Bitbucket/Kiln. If you can, you may be able to make this automatic. If not, you could push to another local copy, which then pushes to both Bitbucket and Kiln using Hooks. See [this answer by Ton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298236/how-to-push-code-to-multiple-servers-by-mercurial/3298493#3298493) (included below for convenience):

> In your central server you create an
>   changegroup hook.
>
> So your central server would have the
>   following hgrc:
>
> ```
> [paths]
> server2=http://server2
> server3=http://server3
> [hooks]
> changegroup.server2 = hg push -f server2
> changegroup.server3 = hg push -f server3
> ```
>
> You can have multiple hooks for the
>   same event, so that shouldn't be an
>   issue.   The advantage of the
>   changegroup hook over the changeset
>   hook is that it is run far less often.

Comment: an anonymous user proposed a change to your post. It is hard to tell if it is valid, could you take a look?

Comment: Oops, apologies, I didn't get any notification of it. I checked the docs (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) and they say for multiple you should use a suffix, so the edit looked good (and has been approved) :-)

Comment: you don't get any notification :) I just thought it would be easier to ask you personally :)