# Push to two repositories that can't reach each other

Tags: mercurial, push, dvcs

The setup:

- a laptop L
- an office server hosting various repositories SOffice
- a customer's database server SCustomer

I'm writing code on L for a customer, and regularly want to push it both to SOffice as well as SCustomer.

I know I could use a `changegroup` hook to push to a third repository from the second (as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3298493/1600)), but this requires that the second can reach the third network-wise.

In my case, each is behind a firewall, and only my laptop typically accesses both through a VPN (or by being physically there). I could set up the VPN on SOffice to get to SCustomer, but I'd rather not.

Is there a way I can, say, set `default` to *two* repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [MultirepoExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MultirepoExtension) that adds commands for doing any operation on multiple repositories.

Or you could create an alias to push to both like:

```
[aliases]
pushboth = !$HG push http://first ; $HG push http://second
```

or you could create a pre-push hook that pushes to the other one.  Something like:

```
[hooks]
pre-push = hg push http://second
```

But I like (and upvoted) krtek's answer the most.  Just give each a path alias and run push twice with the short names instead of the URLs.

Comment: Wouldn't the hook create some kind of infinite loop ? Doesn't the hook get triggered by the second push ? BTW, thanks for the extension, I wasn't aware of it

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to test to make sure it only triggers on push to first.  I'll stick with the run push twice rather than trying to automate it suggestion.  Putting little short cuts like this into your workflow just makes you annoyed when you're on a system without them and confused when they have a side effect you didn't anticipate.

Comment: The extension as well as the pushboth command alias presumably come with the issue that they can't be controlled easily/directly from TorgoiseHg Workbench; fine by me, but I'm looking for a relatively convenient solution for non-devs as well. Still, these are closest.

Answer (score 7):

You can't `default` to two repositories, but you can define more than one repository in your `hgrc` file :

```
[paths]
default= /path/to/first/repo
scustomer = /path/to/second/repo
```

You can then push to the `scustomer` repository explicitly :

```
hg push scustomer
```

If you want to automate the process of pushing to both repository at once, I'm not aware of a Mercurial method to do it, but it is really easy to create a shell script, alias or something else to run both commands one after the other.

You can even use a hook on the repository to automatically push to the other one, but you will have to discriminate between a "manual" push and the automatic push in the hook, and I'm supposing this will be really messy.

Comment: I should have clarified that I know I can set multiple push locations in the `hgrc`.

Comment: Then you should have a look at the extension given by @Ry4an, it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Could you create a second clone of the repository with a hook that automatically pushes to both of the external repositories? Then push from your working clone to the second clone.